# ServiceStack: How do I use custom OAuthProvider to get access to Azure resources

Tags: azure, cors, servicestack

1. Created custom provider that implements: OAuthProvider, IAuthWithRequest.
2. Created AuthenticateAttribute that calls PreAuthenticate() method of the provider.
3. Configured CorsFeature:

   ```
   Plugins.Add(new CorsFeature(new[] {  "http://localhost:23589",  "*" },
           allowCredentials: true,
           allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Allow, Authorization"));
   ```

Problem: when provider's Authenticate method is called to request a code from 
"login.microsoftonline.com" (`authService.Redirect(PreAuthUrlFilter(this, codeRequest));` ) the following error is thrown:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://login.microsoftonline.com/d331431b-899c-4666-8094-e82e6bfc3964/oaut…orts%2fpbi&scope=user_impersonation&state=f8e986304a47427d8c6a76767f2ef573. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:23589' is therefore not allowed access.

What is the correct way to:

1. Request an auth code from Microsoft
2. Get the code back in a query string
3. Request auth Token using the code

Authorization Code Grant Flow Diagram

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [ServiceStack.Authentication.Aad](https://github.com/jfoshee/ServiceStack.Authentication.Aad). At a minimum this should offer a unit-tested reference implementation. Or perhaps you can use the NuGet package directly.

I encourage you to clone the repository where you can step through the stand-alone SelfHostTest as well as unit tests.

To my knowledge, CORS should not be necessary. I may be wrong. But in my implementation the JSON responses coming from Microsoft were handled by the server, not the web browser.

I'm sorry for not including a code sample in this response; it would be difficult to take a single snippet of code from that repository. The entire repository is the answer to your fundamental question.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of that plugin and garner Imaginary Internet Points for its use.*

Comment: Thank you Jacob. I'm using your implementation. It works great until i try to integrate it to my app :). I get to the point when RequestCode is called and then it returns ( return RequestCode(authService, session, userSession, tokens); ) and the error is thrown. If i call Authenticate again the code is null. Can't figure out what i am missing. How to "wait", get the code and then request a token.

Comment: Here is the issue: 1. Client calls a service that needs access to Azure. 2. Service calls AAD AuthenticationProvider. 3. AuthenticationProvider requests a code and returns. 4.Service returns. 5. Microsoft sends the code in the query string but AuthenticationProvider can't get it and continue with the flow.

Comment: Jacob, did you try to add client ?